# Como usar ALIASES no Oracle de forma correta?

Tags: oracle, alias

Eu estou tentando selecionar diversas colunas de uma única tabela, e para facilitar o processo de enxergar os dados e ficar mais fácil de separar as colunas, eu decidi usar aliases.

Mas o problema é que ao rodar o query, ele me retorna o seguinte erro :

> ORA-00923: palavra-chave FROM não localizada aonde esperada

O meu código está assim :

```
SELECT MAX(salary) as 'Maximo Salário' , 
MIN(salary) as 'Minimo Salário', 
SUM(salary) as 'Soma de Todos Salários', 
AVG(salary) as 'Média Salarial' FROM employees
```

Segundo a própria documentação da Oracle se seleciona uma coluna de uma tabela com aliases da seguinte forma :

```
column_name AS alias_name
```

Então, o que eu estou fazendo errado aqui ? Deveria ter algum  `WHERE` neste `SELECT` ? Mas não é obrigatório se ter ele, somente nos casos em que é necessário usá-lo de fato.

Como posso usar de forma correta a aliases, neste `SELECT` ?

Comment: A resposta solucionou seu problema? Se não, tem algo que eu possa fazer para melhorá-la?

Comment: Solucionou sim, só tinha esquecido de colocar como resposta certa. Enfim, coloquei já e novamente agradeço pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Os nomes precisam estar entre aspas duplas, não simples.

```
SELECT MAX(salary) as "Maximo Salário" , 
MIN(salary) as "Minimo Salário", 
SUM(salary) as "Soma de Todos Salários", 
AVG(salary) as "Média Salarial" FROM employees
```

Comment: Meu erro foi um tanto tosco, mas mesmo assim, muito obrigado por ter respondido tão rápido, funcionou certinho. +1 e resposta certa (tem que se esperar um tempo para se colocar como reposta certa).

Comment: @Monteiro Essas coisas acontecem. Bom poder ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Complementado com alguns pontos:

A utilização do `AS` quando utilizado para nomear colunas é opcional, [exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/92c98b/2):

```
SELECT 
      MAX(salary) "Maximo Salário" , 
      MIN(salary) "Minimo Salário", 
      SUM(salary) "Soma de Todos Salários", 
      AVG(salary) "Média Salarial" 
FROM employees
```

Se o alias a ser escolhido não possuir mais de uma palavra, pode se abster da utilização das aspas duplas, [exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/92c98b/4):

```
SELECT 
  MAX(salary) MaximoSalario , 
  MIN(salary) MinimoSalario, 
  SUM(salary) SomaDeTodosSalarios, 
  AVG(salary) MediaSalarial 
FROM employees
```

Existe a possibilidade de fazer a referencia de um alias em `ORDER BY`, [exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15b91f/7):

```
SELECT 
  MAX(salary) "Maximo Salario" , 
  MIN(salary) MinimoSalario, 
  SUM(salary) SomaDeTodosSalarios, 
  AVG(salary) MediaSalarial,
  dep
FROM employees
group by dep
order by "Maximo Salario"
```

Uma outra utilização útil do `AS` e na construção de uma `QUERY` que utiliza `SUB QUERY`, [exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d92227/1):

```
WITH 
   avg_sal AS (
      SELECT AVG(salary) avg FROM employees),
   emp_dep AS (
      SELECT name, salary FROM employees where dep = 10)


SELECT * FROM emp_dep where salary > (select avg from avg_sal)
```

---

Observações:

- Utilizando aspas duplas, o Oracle é case-sensitive.
- Se não utilizar aspas duplas, o Oracle interpretará tudo como maiúsculo.
- Evite utilizar o mesmo identificador para duas colunas.
- Cada versão do Oracle possuí um limite específico para um identificador.

Neste [exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d92227/6), internamente o Oracle definirá o identificado `MAXIMO` para ambas as colunas, se tentar utilizar esse identificado, receberá um erro: [`ORA-00960`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/e900.htm#ORA-00960):

```
SELECT 
  MAX(salary) "MAXIMO" , 
  MIN(salary) maximo
FROM employees
order by maximo
```